# If all the numbers $(1^\alpha,\,2^\alpha,\,3^\alpha,\,\dotsc)$ are integer, then $\alpha$ is an integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, irrational-numbers

A theorem of Siegel asserts that

> If $\beta>0$ and $2^\beta,\,3^\beta,\,5^\beta$ are integers, then $\beta$ is an integer.

The following result is a beautiful consequence of this theorem

> If $\beta$ is a positive number such that $1^\beta,\,2^\beta,\,3^\beta,\,\dotsc$ are integers, then $\beta$ is itself is an integer.

I'm looking for a proof of this result.

*Note*. This result appeared as a problem in the 1972 Putnam Prize competition, and not one of more than 2000 university student competitors gave a solution; the solution, though not hard, could well elude even a professional mathematician for several hours (or days).

Comment: I fixed typos in the title. Is it OK ?

Comment: This is a restatement of Problem A6 from the 1971 Putnam; a solution appears [here](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html).

Comment: We may notice that it is a pretty straightforward consequence of Baker's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem).

Comment: @vadim123: oh, now I see. The solution through finite differences is very nice and tricky!

Comment: Very beautiful consequence (this is true) but insubstantial because I use Siegel and then all the others must be integers because the exponent is integer. What would be extremely beautiful is taking just two of the two numbers 2, 3, 5 of Siegel. Maybe you want to get this result without using Siegel (in whose case the question becomes pertinent)?

Comment: I can't edit my other comment. I wanted to say is show the consequence suggested by k1.M without using Siegel (in any way to reduce the three bases to two ones which must be impossible given the genius of Siegel). I have problems with my poor english.

Comment: There is a solution for the problem with using finite differences, however the generalisation of the Siegel theorem for two bases is open.

Comment: Hi k1.M. I don´t believe this problem (two bases) be pertinent to ask. It is almost sure that 3 is the minimum possible found by the great (a giant, like Baker and few more men because number trascendental theory is extremely difficult) Siegel. The algebraic numbers are countable so trascendental have the power of continum but it was only In 1851, Liouville discover the first trascendental known.Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Well, k1.M, here an extension of important and beautiful Siegel Theorem (I did not know). It is clear $\beta$ must be integer or irrational and by another theorem of Siegel $\beta$ must be trascendental. I guess the statement goes for any three coprime integer x, y, z the triple 2, 3, 5 having been chosen for smallest.Thus the true spirit of the statement of Siegel would be "***all trascendental as exponent of an integer can gives an integer at most twice***".

Comment: The sentence written in bold letters is the same Teorem of Siegel taking 2,3,5 and is just to say it is VERY PROFOUND despite some persons  might think.